# External javascript-not working

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, validation

I am having an issue while using external java script. I am making some mistake due to which form validation is not doing well. It is doing well when java script code is internal. When I place it in external file it is doing nothing. Here is the code.

> html

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Data management system</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
     <div class="header"></div>
     <div class="continer">
         <div class="myForm1" style="height:200px; width:300px; float:left;">
            <h2>MTC</h2>
            <form name="myForm1" action="access.jsp" method="get" onsubmit="return validateMtc()">
                <br/>MSISDN:<input type="text" name="MISDN" maxlength="11">
                <br/>RECIEPIENT:<input type="text" name="recipient" maxlength="12">
                <br/>DONOR:<input type="text" name="donor" maxlength="10">
                <br/>Date:<input type="text" name="date" value="">
                <br/>RN#:<input type="text" name="rn" value="" maxlength="5">
                <br/>Issue:<input type="text" name="Issue" maxlength="13">
                <br/>SR:<input type="text" name="SR" maxlength="14">

                <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><input type="reset" name="Reset">


            </form>


        </div>
        <div class="myform2" style="float:left; height:200px; width:300px;">
            <h2>O.C.S</h2>

        </div> 
        <div class="myform3" style="float:left; height:200px; width:300px;">
            <h2>K.B.C</h2>

        </div>

     </div>
 </div>



</body>
```

> myscript.js

```
//alert(1);
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
var Datee=/^[0-9-]*$/ig;///^\d{1, 2}\/\d{1, 2}\/\d{4}$/;    
var alpha_Numeric=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ig;
var alpha=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var a = document.forms["myForm1"]["MISDN"].value;
var b = document.forms["myForm1"]["Issue"].value;
var c = document.forms["myForm1"]["SR"].value;
var d = document.forms["myForm1"]["date"].value;
var e = document.forms["myForm1"]["recipient"].value;
var f = document.forms["myForm1"]["donor"].value;
var g = document.forms["myForm1"]["rn"].value;
var h = document.forms["myForm2"]["MISDN"].value;
var i = document.forms["myForm2"]["SR"].value;
var j = document.forms["myForm2"]["reason"].value;
var k = document.forms["myForm3"]["MSISDN"].value;
var l = document.forms["myForm3"]["SR"].value;
function validateMtc()
{


if(a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "")
{          
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();
    document.myForm1.date.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!a.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!(b.match(alpha_numeric)))   
{  
    alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only in ISSUE field');  
    document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
    return false;
}  
else if(!c.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only SR field');  
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!d.match(Datee))
{
    alert('Please input correct date in DATE field (dd-mm-yy)');  
    document.myForm1.date.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!e.match(alpha))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets only in reciepeint filed');  
    document.myForm1.recipient.focus();
    return false;

}
else if(!f.match(alpha))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets only in donor field');  
    document.myForm1.donor.focus();
    return false;

}
else if(!g.match(alpha_Numeric))
{
    alert('Please input aplhabets and numerics only in RN# field');  
    document.myForm1.rn.focus();
    return false;

}
else
    return true;
//alert("!!!!!!!!");
}
function validate_ocs()
{
if(h == "" || i == "" || j == "")
{  
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm1.Issue.focus();
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();
    document.myForm1.date.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!h.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm2.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!i.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only SR field');  
    document.myForm2.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!(j.match(alpha_numeric)))   
{  
    alert('Please input numeric and alphabets only in ISSUE field');  
    document.myForm2.Issue.focus();
    return false;
}  
else
    return true;

}
function validate_kbc()
{
if(k == "" || l == "")
{  
    alert("Manadotry fields should not left blank");
    document.myForm1.MISDN.focus();
    document.myForm1.SR.focus();

    return false;
}
else if(!k.match(numbers))
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in MSISDN field');  
    document.myForm3.MISDN.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!l.match(numbers))  
{
    alert('Please input numeric characters only in SR field');  
    document.myForm3.SR.focus();
    return false;
}
else
    return true;

}
//alert('!!!');
```

Comment: if using a 3rd party library is an option, why not try the excellent JQuery Validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @ChaoticNadirs Requirement is to do in JS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems to be working if you remove the document.alert("!!") or replace it by just alert("!!!")

```
function validateMtc()
{
//document.alert("!!!!!!!!");
```

regex for alphanumerics:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ig
```

regex for numbers and dashes:

```
/^[0-9\-]*$/ig
```

Comment: The thing about validating. If there's an error it will skip through... please try and replace document.alert("!") with alert("!") - if the script gets loaded at all it should show. And then move the alert down your code to see where it fails. It works fine here

Comment: for fun - place an alert(1); as the very first line before function, so it will show on load of document, not on submit. Just so you know the script gets loaded

Comment: check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myDxA note, that I have only put the fixedwidth class on the first two to porve the point

Comment: hello @Steen my js code is again not working :/ . I have added couple of functions in same js file. And put alert(1) in start of script. It is giving me alert on loading of script. Should i edit my question and paste js code again ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is warning against "discussion"... :-) But that that alert(1) and move it down your code one line at a time. When it dosen't work you have your error just before. Or edit the codepen from before with you changes to play around

Comment: I have edit the question with new js code @Steen ! Please tell me my fault !